# PDO как реализовать запись в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Недавно перешел на *PDO*. Спасает от *SQLinjection*.

Но это же прибавило некоторые неудобства:

Хотел добавить в запись *html-теги*, такие как ссылка, изображение, заголовок. Но *PDO* всё обрабатывает через функцию вроде `htmlspecialchars()`.

Как запретить преобразование этих тэгов?

Думаю, как-то надо изменить функцию `prepare()`.

Comment: Это вряд ли, у PDO не должно быть такого функционала. Смотрите, что у вас фильтрует данные на входе (опенкарт, например, таким занимался).

Answer (score 1):

Давно уже перешел на PDO, и таких проблем не возникало.
PDO дает защиту, экранируя переменные в запросе, но суть переменной не меняет.
Сохраняю и ссылки, и теги, и всё работает.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Какой вопрос такой и ответ. Ну как может PDO чистить переменную? Если суть PDO предотвратить изменения структуры запроса, своим шаблоном запроса. Но переменные PDO не чистит. Что бы оставить все теги на месте не нужно чистить функциями вот и все